# Ansible: how do I concatenate attributes of dictionaries from a list?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Suppose I have this list:

```
hosts:
  - {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "www.example.com"}
  - {"ip": "42.42.42.42", "hostname": "www.wikipedia.com"}
```

I want to obtain a string like this (to put it into a template):

```
'1.2.3.4,42.42.42.42'
```

It's similar to what I'd obtain with `hosts|join(',')`, but I only want to concatenate the values of `ip`, so probably I should obtain a list of IPs first... but how?

Answer (score 1):

you could pass the `hosts` to `map(attribute='ip')` filter.

here is a PB to try it:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    hosts:
      - {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "hostname": "www.example.com"}
      - {"ip": "42.42.42.42", "hostname": "www.wikipedia.com"}
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: hosts | map(attribute='ip') | list | join(',')
```

cheers

Comment: You can omit the *list* filter. The filter *join* works with iterable as well *{{ hosts|map(attribute='ip')|join(',') }}*

Comment: Thanks for the tip! @VladimirBotka